# Billing Dashboard for Multi-Cloud Platform

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform

Our cloud platform is about 90% AWS based, with the rest with GCP and Azure.
The financial department is requesting we make a consolidated dashboard that details the monthly cost of each cloud platform.

Do you have any recommendations for a billing dashboard that includes billing information from multiple cloud platforms?

Thank you.

Comment: The options out there like https://cloudcheckr.com/ and https://www.cloudbolt.io/ and whatnot are all going to be a lot more expensive than the easier solution of "finance can log in to three different websites once a month".

Comment: CloudHealth is an option.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud offers an example dashboard to start with:

[Visualize your costs with Google Data Studio](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/visualize-data)

If you need a consolidated dashboard, reading billing data from BigQuery is very easy.